# Heroku logs cluttered

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I just started using Heroku for one of my node apps.

When I run the heroku logs command it is so cluttered that i cant pick out the data I want from all the other information I don't need.

Is there a way to clean up that log output so it's more human friendly?

It's like it just dumps a wall of text at me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [Papertrail](https://addons.heroku.com/marketplace/papertrail) add-on on Heroku for viewing the logs.

It has a free plan which is enough for small application. It gives you flexibility for searching your logs by text and time. A browser URL is provided by Papertrail to view the logs, which is convenient to access from mobile also. Adding this add-on to your application is quite simple, no app changes are required. Below filters are available out of the box on its dashboard to view the logs-

- All events
- Deploys
- Dyno state changes
- Platform errors
- Web app output